# How to create a component that wraps a specific slot in VueJS (like `v-list-item-title` from Vuetify)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

In **Vuetify** there is a `<v-list-item>` component with a few slots (`append`, `prepend`, `subtitle`, `title`). There are also 2 components (`v-list-item-title` and `v-list-item-subtitle`) that **"wrap"** the `#title` and `#subtitle` slots so you can use them directly inside the `<v-list-item>` component if you want to pass a something to the appropriate slots instead of having to create a `<template>` tag to wrap the content you want to pass.

So you can do:

```js
<v-list>
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in [ 1, 2, 3 ]" :key="index" :value="index">
        <v-list-item-title>
           Title: {{ item }}
        </v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>
           STitle: {{ item }}
        </v-list-item-subtitle>
        Content
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

instead of:

```js
<v-list>
   <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in [ 1, 2, 3 ]" :key="index" :value="index">
        <template #title>
            Title: {{ item }}
        </template>
        <template #default>
            Content
        </template>
        <template #subtitle>
            STitle: {{ item }}
        </template>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

**So how can I create a component like `<v-list-item-title>` for the `append` slot for example?**

Answer (score 1):

This might be a misconception, when you put a `<v-list-item-title>` in the default slot, it does not end up where the `#title` slot would go, but stays in the default slot. You can add several titles through the default slot, even along with using the title slot.

Have a look at the [code for VListItem](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/05d1ab34b7336d085e2567a6b9b24846c48ad4e4/packages/vuetify/src/components/VList/VListItem.tsx#L273-L287). In non-tsx, it would look something like this:

```html
<div class="v-list-item__content" data-no-activator="">

  <v-list-item v-if="$slots.title || props.title">
    <slot name="title" :title="props.title">
      {{props.title}}
    </slot>
  </v-list-item>

  <slot v-bind="slotProps"/>

</div>
```

So there is a VListItem that is only rendered when `#title` slot or `props.title` is provided, where `props.title` is the default content, which will be overridden by the slot.